# Not clickable Transform data in Power BI menu

Tags: powerquery

I've already uploaded data from SQL Analysis services, and after this I can make any calculations or make any changers in the report because Transform data is unclickable and I cannot use Power Query Editor .
But if I upload data from SQL Server then everything works fine.
Could you help me, please, find the reason why I cannot work with data from SQL Analysis services?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to work with Analysis Services. When using the UI, the default way is to connect to the whole data model. That means you can use all the pre-defined measures for example. If you want to add additional tables to that model, you have to change the connection to direct query. This is a preview feature that must be enabled by your admin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services
If so, you should see a clickable link at the right bottom like so:
[image]

If you clik on it, a dialogue like this should pop up:
[image]

After accepting your are able to click on "Transform data" to import more sources.